# Understanding $\mathbb{E}_x$ or $\mathbb{P}_x$ for Markov chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a probability space 
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$
, and a stochastic process 
$\{X_n: \Omega \rightarrow S\}$
 (assume $S$ is countable).
The definition of Markov chain is there exists a transition probability $p$ such that 
$$\mathbb P[\{X_{n+1} = y\}|\sigma(X_0,\cdots, X_n)] = p(X_n, y)$$

We define a new probability space $(S^\mathbb{N}, \otimes_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{S}, \tilde{\mathbb{P}})$ by applying the
Kolmogorov extension theorem on the joint distribution $\mu_{(X_0, \cdots, X_k)}$ and sending $k$ to infinity. Also define $\tilde X_n$ to be the projection map for $\omega \in S^\mathbb{N}$ where $\tilde X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$

(It seems that $\mathbb{P}$, $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ and $X_n, \tilde X_n$ are often used interchangeably.)

> Now if we were given that $X_0$ has an initial distribution which is a
>   Dirac at the point $x\in S$, what is the exact definition of
>   $\mathbb{P}_x$ (it is actually $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x$).

Durrett only says $\mathbb{P}_x$ is a basic object since in general, we have 
$$\mathbb{P}_\mu(y)= \int_S  \mathbb{P}_x(y) d\mu(x).$$
Furthermore, according to Durrett's notation for Markov property, here it should really be $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x$ instead of ${\mathbb{P}}_x$.

Just given a r.v $X_0:\Omega \rightarrow S$ with some distribution $\mu$, and some r.v. $H: \Omega \rightarrow S$, I know the defintion of 
$$\mathbb{E}[H|X_0 = x] = g(x)$$ where $g$ is a $\mu$-a.e. defined function from
$$\mathbb{E}[H|\sigma(X_0)] = g(X_0).$$
Now for some measurable $A\subset S^\mathbb{N}$, I don't think we can say
$$\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A) = \tilde{\mathbb{E}}[1_A | \tilde X_0 = x]$$
because the right hand side is defined regardless what the distribution of $X_0$ is...

Edit:

> So suppose $X_0$ has some distribution $\mu$, it would still make
>   sense to define "$\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A) = \tilde{\mathbb{E}}[1_A |
>  \tilde X_0 = x]$" which will give us a function of $x$ that is defined
>   up to $\mu$ a.e. Then the notation $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A)$ is not
>   only defined for when $X_0$ has the Dirac distribution at $x\in S$.
>   But when we see "$\mathbb{P}_x$" why do we always assume "the process
>   starts at $x$" or to say $X_0=x$ a.e., $\mu_{X_0} = \delta_x$?

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. The definition of $\tilde{\mathbb P}_x$ looks fine to me.

Comment: "(It seems that $\mathbb{P}$, $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ and $X_n, \tilde X_n$ are often used interchangeably.)" No, at least here they are not since $\mathbb{P}$ and $X_n$ refer to any process on any probability space fitting the definition while $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ and $\tilde X_n$ refer to the specific choice $(S^\mathbb{N}, \otimes_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}, \tilde{\mathbb{P}})$ and $\tilde X_n$ the projection map. "what is the exact definition of $\mathbb{P}_x$ (it is actually $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x$)" Again, no.

Comment: "for some measurable $A\subset S^\mathbb{N}$, I don't think we can say $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A) = \tilde{\mathbb{E}}[1_A | \tilde X_0 = x]$" Actually we can, and we do.

Comment: So suppose $X_0$ has some distribution $\mu$, it would still make sense to define "$\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A) = \tilde{\mathbb{E}}[1_A | \tilde X_0 = x]$" which will give us a function of $x$ that is defined up to $\mu$ a.e. Then the notation $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x(A)$ is not only defined for when $X_0$ has the Dirac distribution at $x\in S$. But when we see "$\mathbb{P}_x$" why do we always assume "the process starts at $x$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Durrett, the measure $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x$ not obtained from "$\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ conditioning on $X_0$".

The first step is to fix some initial distribution $\mu$ for $X_0$, then apply Kolmogorov Extension theorem to this specific case 
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_0\in B_0, \cdots X_n \in B_n) = \int_{B_0} \mu(dx_0) \int_{B_1} p(x_0, dx_1) \cdots\int_{B_n} p(x_{n-1}, dx_n)$$
to obtain a measure $\tilde{\mathbb P}_\mu$ on the sequence space $(S^{\mathbb{N}}, \mathcal{S}^{\mathbb{N}})$.

So for different $x,y \in S$, we actually apply Kolmogorov Extension theorem twice (for $X_0 \sim \delta_x$ and $X_0 \sim \delta_y$) to obtain  $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_x$ and $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_y$.